# Como ajeitar o Auto Increment que está populando números altos no bd Heroku?

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, spring-boot, heroku, flyway

Estou codificando uma ***API RESTful*** com **Spring Boot v.2.0** e etc. O caso é que, quando eu tento fazer um *deploy* para o **Heroku** usando *migration* (**Flyway**) de inserção os **ids** ficam com valores altos.

Minha *model* ou *entidade* de **Usuario** esta com o **id** assim:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
```

E mesmo se eu fizer o *inserte* na "mão grande" pelo **MySQL Workbench** ele fica com o id assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

*Hellp*!

Comment: Seu problema é o "39" no campo *id*? Se sim, existe algum motivo especial para isso te incomodar? "Buracos" na sequencia não deveriam quebrar a aplicação... No InnoDB você não pode resetar o AUTO_INCREMENT para um valor menor do que o max() da coluna, mas pode usar `ALTER TABLE nome_da_tabela AUTO_INCREMENT = 1` se truncar sua tabela antes...

Comment: É entao, eu faço o truncate e nao faço nada depois, vou tentar ver se isso funciona de dar um alter na tbl. Valeu.